# Probability cut-off value for Logistic Regression

Tags: regression

I'm doing a project in predicting default risk for SBA loans using R. My data has 187,986 positives and only 17796 negatives (9.46%). Clearly this is an imbalanced dataset. That's why when I run accuracy rate checking for my model using probability cutoff value=0.5, the accuracy result is way too low as below,

```
> mytestset$LoanStatus_PIF<-ifelse(mytestset$LoanStatus_PIF=="PIF",1,0)
> pred<-predict(final,newdata=mytestset,type="response")
> y_pred_num<-ifelse(pred>0.5,1,0)
> mean(y_pred_num==mytestset$LoanStatus_PIF)
```

Result:
[1] 0.009682553

When I change the cutoff value to 0.998 and up, the result is way much impressive:

```
> y_pred_num<-ifelse(pred>0.5,1,0)
> mean(y_pred_num==mytestset$LoanStatus_PIF)
Result: 
[1] 0.9997752
```

Question:
1. Will my model be rejected because I manually choose the cut-off value?

2. Does 0.999 make sense for a cutoff value? As common cut-off value is usually 0.5.
   Thanks !

Comment: This really depends of the difference in cost between false negatives and false positives.  You might then be able to find a sensible cut-off using cross-validation

Comment: Hi Henry, the more I increase the cutoff value, the more accuracy rate increase and it reaches 1 if cutoff value=0.999. What does it mean by "Sensible value"? do I have to reduce the accuracy rate in exchange for a lower cut-off value? As when I reduce the cut-off value to under 0.991, the accuracy falls down to only 0.65xxx.

Comment: I suggest looking around for what our member Frank Harrell has to say about cutoff values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your question.
I think that in order for us to provide you with a good answer, some additional information might be needed.  I'll do my best to address what I see as the main issue here, and you can let me know if I'm missing the point of your question.

As you say, you have an imbalanced dataset.  Whenever this is the case, looking at simply the "accuracy" (number of correctly flagged observations among all observations; i.e., (true positives + true negatives) / Total) can be very misleading.

To illustrate this in a situation such as yours, where one class is relatively rare, consider the most naive model that simply assigns a label of "positive" to every observation, regardless of probability (akin to taking a cutoff value of 0 or 1).  This model would have an accuracy of 0.9135!
But "accuracy" hides what is really going on because of the class imbalance. In reality, you have an accuracy of 0% with the 17,796 "negatives" and an accuracy of 100% with the far-more-frequent 187,986 "positives."  What happened is that your model outsmarted you:  after all, why should it take the effort to discriminate between "positives" and "negatives" when it can be correct >90% of the time no matter what else it does?

@Henry suggested correctly that you can force your model to care about discrimination by assigning "costs" to wrong decisions.  However, for the more immediate concern of describing your model's performance, **you need to disregard accuracy, as accuracy in this context is too misleading to be used (alone) to choose a "cutoff" value.**

Other performance metrics that can be computed from your data might be of more use to you: for example, the [F1 score](https://machinelearningmastery.com/classification-accuracy-is-not-enough-more-performance-measures-you-can-use/) is a composite metric of precision and recall, which tends to be far more robust to class imbalances.

I would suggest this: if you are truly just looking for a cutoff value,create a vector of possible cutoffs, such as:

```
test <- data.frame(prob = seq(1/1000, 1, length.out = 1000), val = NA)
```

Then, loop through each cutoff value, computing the metric of choice (like F1) and determine where you reach an optimal value.  This approach is far from complete, and may still be rejected if you can't properly defend it, but it is far less vulnerable than what you've proposed:

```
###Here's a quickly written function you can use to compute various performance metrics
ConfusionStats <- function(model, threshold){
  DF <- model.frame(model)
  DF$prob <- predict(model, type = "response")
  DF$flag <- ifelse(DF$prob > threshold, 1, 0)
  Tab <- table(DF[[fit$formula %>% as.character %>% `[`(2)]], DF$flag) %>% as.data.frame

  return(list(TP = Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1],
          FP = Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 0 & Tab$Var2 == 1],
          TN = Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 0 & Tab$Var2 == 0],
          FN = Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 0],
          Accuracy = (Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 0 & Tab$Var2 == 0]) / (Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 0 & Tab$Var2 == 0] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 0 & Tab$Var2 == 1] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 0]),
          PPV =  Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] / ( Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 0 & Tab$Var2 == 1]),
          Precision = Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] / ( Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 0 & Tab$Var2 == 1]),
          Recall = Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] / (Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 0]),
          Sensitivity = Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] / (Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 0]),
          F1 = 2 * ( (Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] / ( Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 0 & Tab$Var2 == 1]) *
                        Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] / (Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 0]))
                     /( Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] / ( Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 0 & Tab$Var2 == 1]) +
                          Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] / (Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 1] + Tab$Freq[Tab$Var1 == 1 & Tab$Var2 == 0])))))}

###And here's where you use the function and do the looping and visualize the curve
for(i in 1:1000){
  test$val[i] <- ifelse(length(ConfusionStats(threshold = test$prob[i], model = final)$F1) == 0, NA, ConfusionStats(threshold = test$prob[i], model = final)$F1)
}
plot(test)
```

Comment: Thanks Vece. I'll try that out !

Answer (score 2):

As @Henry notes in a comment, this is really a question about how you evaluate the relative costs of false-positive and false-negative classifications. That relative cost directly corresponds to your choice of a probability cutoff. Considerations of accuracy without taking into account relative costs are not very helpful. The "common cut-off value" of 0.5 only makes sense if both types of misclassification are equally costly.

Say that the cost of a false positive and that of a false negative are scaled proportionately to sum to 1 and that your model is close to the true model. Then with the cost of a false-positive classification being *c*, and the cost of a false negative thus (1-*c*), you choose *c* as the probability cutoff value from your model to minimize your overall cost. (See [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d670/6b6e626c15680688b0774419662f2341caee.pdf) by Buja et al on proper scoring rules, page 13, which also suggests ways to improve performance by using other loss functions in your model to focus attention near particular prior choices of *c*.)

To answer your questions in this context:

1. Your model should be evaluated based on its ability to predict probabilities of class membership or net misclassification costs, rather than its accuracy at any particular choice of classification cutoff *c*.
2. Choose a cutoff value *c* that represents the relative costs. With a good model, if you set a cutoff of *c* = 0.998 you have the corresponding cost of a false negative as 0.002, and you are evaluating the cost of a false positive as almost 500 times that of a false negative. If that makes sense for your application, use it. If not you should use a cutoff that more closely represents the estimated relative costs. As your model is not necessarily close to the true model, consider @Henry's suggestion to use cross-validation, or alternatively bootstrapping, to find the choice of *c* that minimizes costs.

Comment: Thanks EdM for the answer !